# PUN2 nonmaster client cannot leave room

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

I have a 2 player board game where one client is the master client and creates a room which the second client then joins via `JoinRandomRoom`.

My intention is that once a game has ended, if both players choose to they can have a rematch, but if either player chooses not to rematch they are both removed from the room and sent back to the menu.

If either player hits **Menu** an RPC call is sent that tells the network manager to run this method:

```csharp
public void LeaveRoom()
{
    PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
}
```

Every time I run it however, the nonmaster client gets an error after a few seconds saying

> Cannot send to: wss://GCASH1025.exitgames.com:443/game. The current
> state of the connection is not Open.

OnLeftRoom is never called by the nonmaster client (which is how the menu transition is handled) and if I try to just join a new random room after "leaving" I get a new error:

> JoinRandomRoom failed. Client is on GameServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking) but not ready for operations (State: Leaving). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.

When I check the `CurrentRoom` and `IsConnected` values for the nonmaster client, they both say that it is still in the room and still connected.

Any suggestions?